# Como saber que checkbox no esta marcado y alertar a usuario Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente caso, tengo una encuesta donde el usuario esta llenando marcado las respuestas afirmativas o negativas, pero estoy teniendo problemas o falta de ideas en como detectar que Check Box no estan marcado y alertar al usuario.

Este es mi adaptadorpreguntas

```
  class adaptadorpreguntas(
    private val context : Context,
    private val listpreguntaspreuso: ArrayList<epreguntas2>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adaptadorpreguntas.PreguntasViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): PreguntasViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        return PreguntasViewHolder(
            layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_estructura_preguntas, parent, false)
        )
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreguntasViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val item = listpreguntaspreuso[position]
    holder.render(item)
    holder.displayChecked(item.answer)


}
override fun getItemCount(): Int = listpreguntaspreuso.size





inner class PreguntasViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val binding = ActivityEstructuraPreguntasBinding.bind(view)
    private val idpregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtidpregunta)
    private val numeropregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtnumeropregunta)
    private val pregunta = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtpreguntas)
    private val imgestado = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icosemaforo)
    private val subitems = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtsubitem)
    var categoria: String = ""
    var itemp : String = ""
    var indicador : String = ""
    var aplicana : String = ""
    //FUNCIONES
    fun render (epreguntas: epreguntas2){
        idpregunta.text = epreguntas.id_pregunta
        categoria = epreguntas.IDCATEGORIA
        itemp = epreguntas.ITEM
        subitems.text = epreguntas.SUBITEM
        numeropregunta.text = epreguntas.ITEM
        pregunta.text = epreguntas.pregunta
        indicador = epreguntas.INDICADOR
        aplicana = epreguntas.APLICANA
        Glide.with(imgestado.context).load(epreguntas.icono_estado).into(imgestado)


    }


    private val checkboxAnswers = mapOf(
        binding.chbksi2 to Answer.SI,
        binding.chbkno to Answer.NO,
        binding.chbkna2 to Answer.NA,


    )
    init {
        // establecer el oyente en todas las casillas de verificación
        checkboxAnswers.keys.forEach { checkbox ->
            checkbox.setOnClickListener { handleCheckboxClick(checkbox) }
            //checkbox.setOnClickListener { valorcheck(checkbox) }
        }
    }
    
    // Una función que maneja todas las casillas de verificación
    private fun handleCheckboxClick(checkbox: CheckBox) {

        // obtener el elemento para la posición que muestra el VH
        val item = listpreguntaspreuso[adapterPosition]

        // actualice el estado marcado del elemento con la respuesta asociada con esta casilla de verificación
        // Si solo se ha -desmarcado-, eso significa que no hay nada marcado
        checkboxAnswers[checkbox]?.let { answer ->
            item.answer = if (!checkbox.isChecked) null  else answer
            // recuerde notificar al adaptador (para que pueda volver a mostrar y desmarcar cualquier otra casilla)
            notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition)
        }
    }

    fun displayChecked(answer: Answer?) {
        // establecer el estado marcado para todas las casillas, verificado si coincide con la respuesta
        // y desmarcado de lo contrario.
        // Establecer cada cuadro de cualquier manera borra cualquier estado anterior del último elemento mostrado
        checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
            checkbox.isChecked = answerType == answer
        }
    }
    fun displayAnswers(answers: Collection<Answer>) {
        // iterar sobre cada par de casilla de verificación/respuesta, ocultando o mostrando según corresponda
        checkboxAnswers.forEach { (checkbox, answerType) ->
            checkbox.visibility = if (answerType in answers) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        }
        }

    }

}
```

Y en mi Activity se muestra el recyclerview de esta manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que para saber que checkbox esta marcado o no, es con el **isChecked** , pero en en un recyclerview tengo que recorrer la posición y preguntar si los checkbox estan marcado o no marcado, pero no tengo idea de como realizarlo, alguna idea.

Comment: Como obtienes la referencia de los chekcbox?

Comment: Lo que usualmente haces es recorrer la lista; `listpreguntaspreuso`. que podría tener otra propiedad ej `estáChequeado` que la seteas en `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. Entonces luego recorres la lista con un `foreach` y listo

Comment: Asi tu idea completa la solución que aplique, gracias.